# Find the system of equations which describes subspace L*orthogonal to L

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question I'm stuck on:

I have a Linear subspace L, given by the following system of equations:

$$ 2x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3 - x_4 = 0 $$
$$ 3x_1 + 2x_2 - 2x_4 = 0 $$
$$ 3x_1 + x_2 + 9x_3 - x_4 = 0 $$

Find the system of equations which describes subspace L*, orthogonal to L.

So, I have done the following steps to solve the question:

1. Put the linear system of equations into matrix form
2. Put this matrix into row-reduced echelon form, which shows we have linear independence (because of full rank)
3. Gram-Schmidt process, to get an orthogonal basis.

Are my first three steps correct? What do I do next?

Answer (score 1):

The equations in a system can be converted in column vectors of the orthogonal subspace.

Between 2 and 3, add a fourth column in your matrix that is linearly indepent from the 3 others (for instance $(1,0,0,0)^T$)

Gram-Schmidt will provide a basis where the first 3 vectors are in L* and the last in L. As L is orthogonal to L, your last column can be transform in the equation of L*